# How to display one calender at a time in prime ng using angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng

i need to display one calender at a time and want other calender to be closed, if i click on other calender.

I have used prime ng calender.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="show"> Date</label>
        <p-calendar  [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="1910:2020" showButtonBar="true" dateFormat="mm-dd-yy" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy"></p-calendar>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>Last Occurance</label>
        <p-calendar  [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="1910:2020" showButtonBar="true" dateFormat="mm-dd-yy" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy"></p-calendar>
      </div>
```

Comment: you can create custom directive( i.e outsideclick ) for this and you can close calendar when user click on outside of it

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/EbxBbI

Comment: @machadevendher Thanks for response, i will try and update you

Comment: i have 2 calenders na, does this work?

Comment: yeah it will work

Answer (score 1):

Take different `ngModel` for multiple calenders

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label class="show"> Date</label>
    <p-calendar id="date1" [(ngModel)]="date1" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="1910:2020" showButtonBar="true" dateFormat="mm-dd-yy" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy"></p-calendar>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>Last Occurance</label>
    <p-calendar id="date2" [(ngModel)]="date1" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="1910:2020" showButtonBar="true" dateFormat="mm-dd-yy" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

**In ts:**

```
export class CalendarDemo {
        date1: Date;
        date2: Date;
    }
```

[**Here is an example**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)

Comment: even now both are opening

Comment: i mean, now i open one calender, it is opened.. again i click on another calender, so both calenders are open, i want one calender to be opened at a time

Comment: send you send prime ng, website link once/

Comment: i have used the same link which u gave me

Comment: what happens if you give seperate id's?

Comment: Seperate id means? i gave date1 and date2 in [(ngModel)]

Comment: `id="date1"` and `id="date2"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174794/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-sravan).